# Tamanho da fonte da legenda num gráfico feito em python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Gostaria de saber como ajustar o tamanho da fonte utilizada em uma legenda em um gráfico feito em Python utilizando a biblioteca matplotlib. Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei esta forma.

```
plt.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size':12})
```

Tem outra maneira de ajustar o tamanho da fonte da legenda de tal forma que ela fique proporcional ao tamanho da figura?

Answer (score 1):

Se você adicionar isto ao código, todas as suas figuras geradas terão a mesma fonte na legenda.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 12
```